# does anyone have problems downloading files from ftp server like this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

the problem is that i can't download or list files from my ftp server that is running on ubuntu. When i try from my windows machine there is no problem with that, but when a try from my linux-parrot VM that is runnig on my windows machine i only can access and move from the directories inside ftp server, but when i try to use ls or get only shows the next message:

ftp> ls -l 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.

and the server never respond again.

I've check the fw on my linux VM is disable already.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your VM is most likely behind a NAT and is essentially on a different network to your Windows machine or has some kind of firewall running that is blocking requests.

You can either

1. Use `PASV` as the first command you run before doing anything on the FTP server. This enables "passive" mode where your computer tells the server "you cannot talk to my ports directly, I will initiate and manage all downloads". See [Active vs Passive FTP](https://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/80512/active-v-s-passive-ftp-simplified). Depending on what client you use look in the settings to enable Passive Mode.
2. Change the network type in your VM settings. Typically a VM is NAT'ed to isolate it from your network and use your host as a gateway to allow it to get to the internet. Depending on your VM host software you might need to enable a "bridged" mode.